# Help identifying LEGO set with yellow construction vehicle arm?

Tags: set-identification, city

[image: partly assembled set photo]

Could you please help identify this partly assembled set? I have already scoured the Internet looking for images to no avail. I have looked through the instruction books we have. It has possibly come in a job lot purchase. Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Great question, and thanks for including a photo. There's usually someone here who can identify a set pretty quickly from a photo like that. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is from: [60122-1: Volcano Crawler](https://brickset.com/sets/60122-1/Volcano-Crawler)

[image]